# How to assign the value of a tag through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

So I'm working on an application with a custom tag that formats long strings. I need to update the html inside a div tag with a string. I also need to assign the value of the custom tag with that string, store that html snippet in a variable, and then update the div.

I get this error when running the code below:

```
com.caucho.jsp.JspLineParseException: expected '>' at ''$''
(for tag '<customTag>' at line 511).  The XML tag syntax is: <tag
attr1='value1'>
```

HTML:

```
<div class='floatLeft clearFix bAllNoTop ' id="newText">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function updateText(text){

outputText = "<customTag value=" + "$" +"{" + text + "}" + "convertNewLinesToBreaks='true'/>";

$("#newText").text(outputText);
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your JSP processor is trying to parse your javascript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have some formatting issues with your outputText value. Also in your example, you aren't declaring outputText anywhere so I'm going to assume it's not declared outside the method. If it is you can remove my `var`.

```
function updateText(text){
    var outputText = "<customTag value='${" + text + "}' convertNewLinesToBreaks='true'/>";

    $("#newText").html(outputText);
}
```

Comment: Weird it looked to work for me based on your question. You can see on jsbin here -> https://jsbin.com/xejaye/edit?html,js,console,output . Maybe the issue isn't with the supplied JS but rather somewhere in your jsp.

Comment: Ah I know what happened. It was because it was being rendered as plain text and not html. Edit your response to ".html" instead of ".text" and I'll accept your answer. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: oh ok no worries I was just using what you had, I didn't want to change anything I didn't know if you may or may not need. Should be updated now.